# Form gets submited even though JS function is returning false

Tags: javascript, forms, dom-events, form-submit, buttonclick

Below is a code snippet I took from the html source:

```
<FORM id=SubmitLogon method=post name=submitLogonForm action=/MyLogin/SubmitLogon.do;jsessionid=reQYQqPCZt_6Oc3EkU66XFiC-fWQQ2DHPdCgWYwR5TbT9xsXOsPe!907086402 AutoComplete="off">



    <TR>
        <TD class=logonLabelTdTag>Username&nbsp; </TD>
        <TD align=left>
            <DIV id=wwgrp_username_Id class=wwgrp>
                <DIV id=wwctrl_username_Id class=wwctrl>
                    <INPUT onchange="javascript: this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();" tabIndex=1 onfocus="javascript: this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();" id=username_Id class=logonTextBox maxLength=40 name=username>
                    </DIV>
                </DIV>
            </TD>
        </TR>


        <TR>
            <SCRIPT language=JavaScript1.2 type=text/javascript>
                       $(document).ready(function () {
                    try {
                       $("input[type='text']").each(function(){
                           $(this).attr("autocomplete","off");
                        });
                       }
                   catch (e)
                   { }
                  });
            </SCRIPT>

            <TD class=logonLabelTdTag>Password&nbsp; </TD>
            <TD align=left>
                <DIV id=wwgrp_password_Id class=wwgrp>
                    <DIV id=wwctrl_password_Id class=wwctrl>
                        <INPUT tabIndex=2 id=password_Id class=logonTextBox maxLength=40 type=password value="" name=password>
                        </DIV>
                    </DIV>
                </TD>
            </TR>



            <TR>
                <TD colSpan=2 align=right>
                    <BUTTON onclick=validateLoginCredentials() style="BORDER-TOP-STYLE: none; BORDER-LEFT-STYLE: none; HEIGHT: 39px; WIDTH: 98px; BACKGROUND: none transparent scroll repeat 0% 0%; BORDER-BOTTOM-STYLE: none; BORDER-RIGHT-STYLE: none" type=submit value="Loginn">
                        <IMG src="https://den02qoj.us.oracle.com/images/btn_login.jpg">
                        </BUTTON>
                    </TD>
                </TR>


            </FORM>

<script>
                function validateLoginCredentials(){
                    alert('invoked');
                    
                    var usernameVar = document.getElementById("username_Id").value;
                    var passwordVar = document.getElementById("password_Id").value;
                    //validationIdd_user
                    //validationIdd_password
                    
                    alert('usernameVar is:'+usernameVar);
                    alert('passwordVar is:'+passwordVar);
                    
                    alert('usernameVar length is:- '+usernameVar.length);
                    alert('passwordVar length is:- '+passwordVar.length);
                    
                    document.getElementById("validationIdd").style.visibility = 'hidden';
                    document.getElementById("validationIdd_user").style.visibility = 'hidden';
                    document.getElementById("validationIdd_password").style.visibility = 'hidden';
                       
                    if(usernameVar == '' && passwordVar == ''){
                        document.getElementById("validationIdd").style.display='';
                        alert('517-false');
                        return false;
                    }else if(usernameVar == '' || usernameVar == null){
                        document.getElementById("validationIdd").style.visibility = 'hidden';
                        document.getElementById("validationIdd_password").style.visibility = 'hidden';
                        document.getElementById("validationIdd_user").style.display='';
                        alert('523-false');
                        return false;
                    }else if(passwordVar == '' || passwordVar == null){
                        document.getElementById("validationIdd_password").style.display='';
                        alert('527-false');
                        return false;
                    }else{
                        alert('530-true submitting now----------------');
                        document.getElementById('SubmitLogon').submit() 
                        return true;   
                    }
                    alert('validateLoginCredentials:end');
                }
            </script>
```

**First time click on submit button**
When `username(id:username_Id)` and `password(id:password_Id)` both are empty the JS function `validateLoginCredentials()` it returned false this I verified by `alert('517-false');` but form got submitted.

**Again when I click on submit button for the second time**
`username(id:username_Id)` and `password(id:password_Id)` both are empty the JS function `validateLoginCredentials()` is invoked but its not entering into the below block (which was the first scenario which I described above).

```
if(usernameVar == '' && passwordVar == ''){
                        document.getElementById("validationIdd").style.display='';
                        alert('517-false');
                        return false;
                    }
```

Why there is different results for the same (above) scenarios
and why form got submitted in first scenario even though JS function returned false?

Please help me out.

Comment: you do not have a `return` in the click  `onclick="return validateLoginCredentials()"` and you probably should be using onsubmit on the form also....

Comment: @epascarello onclick="return validateLoginCredentials()" did not resolve the problem still the form is getting submitted and i'm not using onsubmit on the form, if i use it js function will be invoked twice right.? which i got this knowledge very recently

Answer (score 0):

you have to put the check function in the form tag instead in the button like

```
<FORM id=SubmitLogon method=post onsubmit="return validateLoginCredentials()" name=submitLogonForm action=/MyLogin/SubmitLogon.do;jsessionid=reQYQqPCZt_6Oc3EkU66XFiC-fWQQ2DHPdCgWYwR5TbT9xsXOsPe!907086402 AutoComplete="off">
```

Comment: thanks, but this works only for first request. i mean once i logged to applicaiton when i click on refresh i'm wantedly redirecting to login page, now in login page when there is no username and password still the form gets submitted. can you pls help me out how to avoid this